# Translate JQuery Mobile widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, internationalization, i18next

Using [i18next](http://i18next.com/), how can I translate JQuery Mobile widgets? Specifically, I'd like to know how to do that without resorting to using `data-i18n-target` to modify generated inner elements, because that is brittle since future widget versions may change the generated code.

Is there a specific page lifecycle event I can subscribe to in order to be able to have i18next modify the DOM before the widget transformation happens?

In this example (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSbEe/)), some markup is correctly translated, but `homeBtn` and `submitBtn` are not:

HTML:

```
<div id="home_page" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a id="homeBtn" href="/" data-icon="home" data-i18n>app.home</a>
        <h2 data-i18n>app.title</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textinput1" data-i18n>app.label</label>
            <input type="text" name="textinput1" id="textinput1" value=""></input>
        </div>
        <form action="">
            <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" data-i18n="[value]app.button" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <center>
            <p data-i18n>app.footer</p>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var i18nOpts = {
    resStore: {
        dev: {
            translation: {
                app: {
                    button: 'Button',
                    home: 'Home',
                    label: 'Label',
                    footer: 'Footer',
                    title: 'i18n Test'
                }
            }
        },
    }
};
i18n.init(i18nOpts).done(function() {
    $("html").i18n();
});
```

Comment: `pagebeforecreate` is the event you need to do your changes before widgets are enhanced. `.page()` widget is enhanced upon that event, but most of other widgets are enhanced on `pagecreate`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2uRpK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile widgets are auto-initialized (Markup enhancement) on two events, `pagebeforecreate` and `pagecreate`. The majority of widgets are initialized once `pagecreate` occurs.

All you need is to wrap *i18n* code in `pagebeforecreate`.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
  // code
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2uRpK/)**

Comment: I want to add that while your answer is correct for the example I proposed, with a single page, it will have to be adapted when multiple pages are being loaded via Ajax, otherwise `i18n.init` will be called every time a page is created. It seems that a good solution in this case is to call `i18n.init` at the start of the application, possibly with the `getAsync: false` option, so that when any page is created, i18next has been initialized and the resources have been loaded. Then the `i18n()` can be called safely in each `pagebeforecreate` event.

Comment: `pagebeforecreate` fires once per page in both single and multi page model, as long as they are pulled via Ajax. `pagecreate` also fires once, but here you can specify page_id selector. `mobileinit` will fire one time per framework using ajax. @FernandoCorreia