# Icon disapears when i18next translation of a href button in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, i18next

The icon of a href button disapears when i18next translation is done in JQuery mobile page

The translation is made in document.ready event, apparently before the JQuery Mobile engine starts,

Thanks ahead

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="Login" >
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" >

        <h1  data-i18n="Login.heading"></h1>        
        <a href="#HelpAboutLogin" id="icoHelpAbout" data-rel="popup" data-icon="info"  data-theme="b" data-iconpos="left" data-i18n="Login.Help_and_About"></a>

    </div><!-- /header -->...
```

javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    i18n.init({ lng:"en" },function(t) {
        // translate nav
        $("body").i18n();

        // programatical access
        //var appName = t("app.name");
        //alert(appName);
    });
});
```

Comment: Everithing is prety straight forword - see edit

Comment: `.ready()` shouldn't be used in JQM. Bind code to `pagebeforecreate` event.

Comment: Just tried it and...
Nothing yet :-(

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545417/translate-jquery-mobile-widgets

Comment: I think the problem is that not all the widgets are auto initialized after this event.
Quote from API: _pagebeforecreate
Triggered on the page being initialized, before **most** plugin auto-initialization occurs._

Comment: True, you should do changes before widgets are created. Text will be lost inside spans once a widget is created.

Comment: Apparently I need an event that trigers **befor** _pagebeforecreate_
If I could manipulate the page befor the Ajax loader loads the specific #Page...

Comment: then try `mobileinit` and place it before loading jquery-mobile.js in head.

Comment: Well, I managed to fix everything using Synchronious load of i18n.init.
Default of i18n init is asynchronious load and Ajax page load seems to race between ..