# Using i18next localization and jquerymobile v1.3.2 in web mobile app anchor style is lost

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, localization, i18next

Hi im using jqm and [i18next](http://i18next.com/). i have successfully applied localization but my anchor tag style is lost when i apply i18next. i have tried trigger and refresh both doesnt work 
 Here is my code
html code

```
<form     id="frmLogin"  action="javascript:GetAction(this);" method="POST">
   <div id="tblLogin" class="loginview">
     <label id="lblId" for="txtid">Member:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtid" value="cendre" data-i18n="[placeholder]attr.placeholderMember;"   data-theme="a" />
        <label id="lblPassword" for="txtpwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="txtpwd" value="cendre123" data-i18n="[placeholder]attr.placeholderPassword;"   data-theme="a" /> 
          <div style="padding-top:10px;"> 
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="button"   id="btnlogin"  data-theme="a" >Login</a>
      </div>
        </div> 
     </form>
```

javascript code

```
 $.i18n.init({
        lng: 'fr',
        ns: { namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.controls'], defaultNs: 'ns.controls'},
        useLocalStorage: false,
        debug: true
    }, function() { 
        $('#lblId').text($.t('index.lblId'));
        $('#lblPassword').text($.t('index.lblPassword'));
        $('#btnlogin').text($.t('index.btnlogin'));
        $('#txtid').i18n();
        $('#txtpwd').i18n();


    });
```

jason lan file code

```
{
    "index": {
      "lblId": "Membre:",
      "lblPassword": "Mot de passe:",
      "btnlogin": "Connexion"
    },
  "attr": {
    "placeholderMember": "Entrez Id de connexion",
    "placeholderPassword": "Entrez Mot de passe" 
  }  
}
```

when i debug my code in firebug it show the code as 
[image]

```
 <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="button" id="btnlogin" data-theme="a">Connexion</a>
```

when i remove i18next localization the code style is fine
[image]

```
 <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="button" id="btnlogin" data-theme="a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Login</span></span></a>
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UAYxg/1/)

Comment: a quick fix `$('#btnlogin .ui-btn-text')` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wHc8s/ check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545417/translate-jquery-mobile-widgets

Comment: post it as an answer i give you some points that may help others

Answer (score 0):

thanks to #Omar this worked for me

```
 $('#btnlogin  .ui-btn-text').text($.t('index.btnlogin'));
```